# twitter-bootstrap button not firing my form .dialog()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The following code works fine without the bootstrap

```
type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
```

stuff in the button declaration. But when used I get a nice blue button but it doesnt fire anything. I include the javascript *(I deleted most of the dialog handling code as I dont even get a dialog)*, and I have an example of the simple forms I am using at the bottom. *(note. "#form-"+tablename is a select list with 3 buttons, "add", "edit" and "delete". I am just trying to get "add" to work right now and to fire off the dialog I made with "#dialog-edit-"+tablename.)*

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">',{
    id:"opener-add-"+tableName,
}).text('Add').appendTo("#form-"+tableName);

$( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName )
    .dialog({ 
        open : function (event,ui){
            if ($( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName ).data("edit_flag") == true){
                init_edit_values(tableName,keyName);
            } else {
                init_create_values(tableName);
            }
        },
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal :true,
        width : 800,
        resizable : true,
        dragable : true,
        buttons : {
            "Update": function() {
            ........etc 
    });


$( "#opener-add-"+tableName ).click(function(e) {
    // I dont even get this far
    alert("well I got a mouse event");
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName ).data("edit_flag",false);
    $( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

and the html of one of the forms

```
<div id="dialog-edit-Stops" title="Add/Edit Stop">
    <form id="dialog-edit-Stops-form">
        <input id="hibernateId" type=hidden><br>
        Stop ID<input id="stopId" size=10 maxlength=10><br>
        Code <input id="stopCode" size=30 maxlength=30><br>
        Name <input id="stopName" size=30 maxlength=30><br>
        Description<input id="stopDesc" size=30 maxlength=30><br>
        URL <input id="stopUrl" size=30 maxlength=100><br>
        Latitude <input id="stopLat" size=30 maxlength=100><br>
        Longitude <input id="stopLon" size=30 maxlength=100><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the resulting working html of the form with select list and my 3 buttons (from Calendar not the Stops above, but they all break). The only difference with the faulty version is the above bootstrap type and class stuff.

Working

```
<form id="form-Calendar">
    <select name="select-Calendar" id="select-Calendar">
        <option value="every_day">every_day</option>
        <option value="not_friday">not_friday</option>
        <option value="not_monday">not_monday</option>
        <option value="not_saturday">not_saturday</option>
        <option value="not_sunday">not_sunday</option>
        <option value="not_thursday">not_thursday</option>
        <option value="not_tuesday">not_tuesday</option>
        <option value="not_wednesday">not_wednesday</option>
    </select>
    <button id="opener-add-Calendar">Add</button>
    <button id="opener-edit-Calendar">Edit</button>
    <button id="opener-delete-Calendar">Delete</button></form>
```

Not working

```
<form id="form-Calendar">
    <select name="select-Calendar" id="select-Calendar">
        <option value="every_day">every_day</option>
        <option value="not_friday">not_friday</option>
        <option value="not_monday">not_monday</option>
        <option value="not_saturday">not_saturday</option>
        <option value="not_sunday">not_sunday</option>
        <option value="not_thursday">not_thursday</option>
        <option value="not_tuesday">not_tuesday</option>
        <option value="not_wednesday">not_wednesday</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button>
    <button id="opener-edit-Calendar">Edit</button>
    <button id="opener-delete-Calendar">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please use Firebug, WebDeveloper extension or something like this in your browser, in order to have a look at the generated source so we can better understand what's the resulting HTML?

Comment: I will try and diff the two, on first look I seem to have lost the button code in the faulty version.

Comment: Diff goes bananas, but the only difference I can see in the buttons is this bootstrap class and type attributes. I pasted the output on the question.

Comment: Ok, as far as I can see the relevant part of HTML and events binding in the Javascript code are correct. One thing we can try is the following: we are creating the buttons dinamically, so maybe when we bind the event, the element is actually not yet in the DOM and so the event gets lost. What we can try is to change `$( "#opener-add-"+tableName ).click(function(e) {` to `$(document).on('click', "#opener-add-"+tableName, function(e) {` .

Comment: the missing ID in the "Add" button (last code part in your question) is just a copy/paste error, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-working resulting-HTML has no ID:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button>
```

Thus, when your code looks for:

```
$( "#opener-add-"+tableName )
```

it can't find it.

Now, I've never added an id the way you are trying as the second parameter: `{id:"opener-add-"+tableName,}`, but I'd try doing it this way instead:

```
$('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">')
    .attr('id',"opener-add-"+tableName).text('Add')...
```

and see if that has better success.  Or, it might be easier to do:

```
   var $btn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">')
        .attr('id',"opener-add-"+tableName).text('Add')...
```

Then, lower in your code assign the event handler to the $btn variable directly:

```
$btn.click(function(e) {
    // I dont even get this far
    alert("well I got a mouse event");
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName ).data("edit_flag",false);
    $( "#dialog-edit-"+tableName ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Comment: I didnt need to store $btn, it worked through setting with attr.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use modals bootstrap?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals